# PHP after a POST FORM, be able to redirect the visitor but continue the POST data insertion

Tags: php, forms, post

Right now i am working on a plateform mostly made in PHP, but i have a specific issue right now.
There is a form, when the button 'submit' is clicked, it redirect you to a php page which will handle all the data you've just posted.
But this process can take a while, so i would like to be able to redirect the customer to another page, but not stoping the previous script.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need AJAX. Or use NodeJS instead of PHP. There is no way you can do it on native PHP.

Comment: @Kirill is right. You're going to need Ajax for this. Ajax can prevent the user from browsing towards the PHP file and only just send the POST request headers to it. Then you can use Javascript to redirect the user to another page while PHP is processing the data.